# How to set string value equal to UITextField?

Tags: xcode, string, button, crash, uitextfield

I'm trying to make it so you type in a number in a text field, then you press a button. A string is then equal to the text field and a label is then equal to the string. The problem is it crashes when i pres the button. What am I doing wrong?

from the .h file:

```
@interface TextGameViewController : UIViewController 
 {
   IBOutlet UITextField *input;
   IBOutlet UILabel *line11;
   NSString *l11;
 }
-(IBAction)button;
```

from the .m file:

```
-(IBAction)button
 {
   [input resignFirstResponder];
   l11 = ([input.text stringValue]);
   line11.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", l11];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

l11 is already a `NSString`, change this line of code from:

```
l11 = ([input.text stringValue]);
```

**To**

```
l11 = input.text;
```